# How to change the User Interface of Tibco Spotfire Webplayer?

Tags: css, tibco, spotfire, tibco-topic

I want to change the user interface of TIBCO spotfire webplayer according to my company theme. I've found the Stylesheets located in the installed directory and make some color change, but when i refresh the login page then nothing happens. It comes with the old blue web player login panel.

I am using spotfire webplayer 7.0.1. I am done with its Co-Branding Part but the blue color doesn't match up with my website theme. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own page and just embed the desired analysis part via iframe, this would give you much more control over the look & feel of the whole thing:

http://www.bearonspotfire.com/how-to-embed-the-spotfire-web-player-inside-a-web-page

Also this: http://spotfire.tibco.com/tips/2014/11/04/integrating-with-javascript-html/

Comment: Dear i dont want to embed the web-player on my website...I want to change the webplayer interface to my own custom color theme...for e.g. i want to change the whole blue color to green which i am not able to do that....By the way thanks for your reply...